# Error: not enough outputs for specified ring size = 7 in monero 0.12.0.0 Lithium Luna

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, sweep-transaction, lithium-luna

[image]I'm having this error:

I've also tried the gui with no luck, rescan and so on.

It's an old wallet, but it should work with sweep_unmixable or sweep_all, but it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is Fixed, check my other post. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/monero-still-in-my-wallet-as-unmixable Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in sweep_unmixable, as evidenced from this recent PR:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3794

I think you should be able to use the latest release-0.12 code, and it should then work.

Comment: I did but still the same

Comment: Then I guess a bug report on https://github.com/monero-project/monero is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a fork of monero, and experience the same problem. How can I understand this issue better? I have only one output and it wants more outputs for ring size 10. I try to send coins generated from the Genesis block to several wallets.