# Monero still in my wallet as unmixable

Tags: ringsize

I can't get monero out of my wallet, It looks like it was old dust accumulated, but it sums out to 8xmr, then I added more fresh monero but now I cant get it out, I've tried sweep unmixable and sweep all in both cli and gui with no luck, always return some other error, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your wallet balance? How many outputs do you have?

Comment: What version is your wallet................?

Comment: I've tried 0.14.0.0 Boron Butterfly and Boron Butterfly, Minor Point Release 0.2

Comment: It said not enough outputs, this is the same problem I had before: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8286/error-not-enough-outputs-for-specified-ring-size-7-in-monero-0-12-0-0-lithium/8315?noredirect=1#comment7237_8315

Comment: I didn't ask what error you got, I asked: "What is your wallet balance? How many outputs do you have?". From the `monero-wallet-cli` you can run the respective commands `balance` and `incoming_transfers available` to get this info.

Comment: This can happen if you have only very small outputs which are too small to pay for themselves in fees. If you're OK with posting this, you can post the output of "incoming_transfers available". This will show the outputs your wallet currently has. It's also possible the wallet software makes bad choices in output selection if your outputs are lopsided.

Answer (score 1):

Actually making smaller transfers fix it, I had 20.9 xmr total and started by making 5.2xmr transfers, then the cli itself break it in 3 or 4 even smaller payments with fees each, but it all when tru at the end, Thank You all for your help!